# Is the Future Progressive suitable in this construction?

Tags: future-perfect, future-continuous

I have come across the following construction in which the examiner used the Future Progressive Tense. Isn't it right to use the Future Perfect Tense?

By 2150, the world's population will be increasing to 10 billion.

Comment: Most people would probably use simple future *By 2150, the world's population **will increase** to 10 billion*. Your "continuous" version implies either an "Indian English" source, or a slightly unusual stylistic choice intended to emphasize the fact that *continuously increasing* global population is an ongoing (past, present, *and* future) process. On the other hand, a native speaker might well say *By 2150, the world's population **will have increased** to 10 billion* to emphasize the fact of reaching a significant "milestone" at that future time, rather than the currently ongoing process.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: l really appreciate your reply. It's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically it is not incorrect, but it presupposes a very special context.

The preposition **by** implies that something will have been completed by that time, therefore the continuous tense is kind of strange.

> By 2150, the world's population **will have increased** to 10 billion.

or

> In 2150, the world's population **will be increasing** to 10 billion.